# Validating Uniqueness within data in another Table

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, validation, ruby-on-rails-4, model

I have a `Student` and `Student_section` model. `Student` table have `student_id and roll_no`, `Student_section` have `student_id, standard_id and section_id`.

`Roll_no` should be unique with in that `standard` and `section`.

In the `student.rb` file I'm having trouble setting up a custom validation for roll_no unique with in that `standard and section` present in `Student_section` model.

I'm having trouble implementing, can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using RAILS 4, you can define relation of model like this and if true, duplcates will be omitted from collection.

```
has_many :student_sections, -> { uniq }, through: :students
```

And if you are using RAILS < 4 version, try this

```
has_many :student_sections, :through => :students, :uniq => true
```

Answer (score 0):

I approve of your usage of a custom validator (which will allow you to explain the conditions which must be met in a consistent and detailed manner via its error message). All you really need to do are make two distinct queries and return based upon their results:

```
def roll_no_must_be_unique
  # Boolean indicating if roll_no is unique within the Student table
  unique_in_student = Student.where(roll_no: roll_no).count == 0
  # Boolean indicating if roll_no is unique within the Standard table
  unique_in_standard = Standard.where(roll_no: roll_no).count == 0

  # Adds the error if either query returned non-unique
  errors.add(:roll_no, 'Error Message Here') unless unique_in_student && unique_in_standard
end
```

If you felt inclined you could simply add an error message after each individual query, indicating in which table it failed. It's really a matter of preference.